# Are there sites that allow for the upload of a full solution for the purpose of troubleshooting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, programming-languages

Are there sites that allow for the upload of a full solution for the purpose of troubleshooting? I've used this site for a while and it's been fantastic. But sometimes I have questions that might not be easily asked/answered without providing my whole VS2010 solution. So are there sites or services where a zipped file can be made available for others to download and take a look at. I realize this type of service would be open to a LOT of misuse by people just looking for others to do their work for them so I kinda doubt that they do exist but still... I'm a self taught hobbyist and most of my info obviously comes from the web. But as you all know this "programming world" is so vast, and changes so fast that finding the right info is sometimes hard. Unfortunately I don't know anyone that I can ask personally or I'd do that. I've even gone to a few local Users group meetings but the info is sooo far over my head that I glean very little from them. I've paid for training classes in video form and these have been great too, but once in a while my questions are just too specific.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The last half of your paragraph is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I agree mellamokb. I just don't want anyone to think I'm a student looking for help with his homework.

Comment: Fair enough.  What's wrong with the myriad of file upload solutions available on the web?  I don't know of anything specifically tailored to VS solutions.  However, SO is probably **not the place** for a question so complicated that it requires the entire solution to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you're willing to put the solution up openly, consider using free project hosting with source control. http://code.google.com/projecthosting/ Google project hosting is only for open-source projects that you are willing to share with everyone.

If you want a free private (non-open source) repository that you can decide who to let see your solution, try http://www.assembla.com. You get 2gb free and unlimited users and repositories. I use assembla for all my projects that aren't open source.

This way you have discussions and full access to the source for people to view and help you with. Not only that but they don't have to download and unzip your solution, they can browse the solution in the repository browser online and view individual files as needed; which is great if the only reason they are looking at the code is to answer questions.

Comment: The Google Code solution looks like a good solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Docs + sharing secured by password or any other free file sharing web sites.